# Localizing text that contains links

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, hyperlink

I have this window where I have a block of text that contains a link. Something like:

Which means only the "here" in the sentence is a hyperlink.

My problem is, I want to prepare this for localization. As a result, I have the text in resx files. So in the resx file I have "Click here to read the documentation" as a string.

So my question is, can I write some xaml that will display that string as a textblock, but display the "here" as a hyperlink? I could theoretically put some tokens to indicate where the hyperlink part starts and ends, I suppose (something like "Click  to read the documentation" in which case I want a hyperlink between .

I know I can use `RichTextBox`, but I believe the hyperlinks in `RichTextBox` only works when ctrl is held down.

Comment: the link is broken, send me to /locathost/#

Comment: The link was just an example. I want to localize the entire string "Click here to read the documention." Where "Click" and "to read the documentation" is normal text, and "here" is a hyperlink to something to be defined later.

Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

strong textstrong textOne way is to split the total text in three parts. One for the text before the hyperlink, hyperlink text itself an one part for the text after the hyperlink.
Your code and resources should look like:

**Code:**

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="{x:Static Properties:Resources.TextBlock_LinkFirstPart}" />
  <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com"
             RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
      <Run Text="{x:Static Properties:Resources.TextBlock_LinkPart}" />
  </Hyperlink>
  <Run Text="{x:Static Properties:Resources.TextBlock_LinkSecondPart}" />
</TextBlock>
```

**Resources:**
[image: image of the resource file]

With the code above you will recive the following result.

[image]

I handle the click in my example in code behind, but it is also possible to bind a command to the hyperlink.

**Code behind:**

```
 private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate( object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e )
 {
    Process.Start( new ProcessStartInfo( e.Uri.AbsoluteUri ) );
    e.Handled = true;
 }
```